# PHP preg_replace - How to get the same result without `/e` `eval` - improved security and speed performance?

Tags: php, regex, security, eval

How to get the same result without `/e` `eval` - improved security and speed performance?

```
function finclude($file){
    return include($file);
}

$str = "Today is {include 'date.php'}.";
echo preg_replace("/\{include '(.*)\'}/e", 'finclude("$1")', $str);
```

date.php:

```
<?php return date('jS \of F'); ?>, 2011
```

Result: `Today is 20th of July.`

Comment: is there a special reason why u don't use the date() function simple in the main app without including the date.php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback`

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/\{include '(.*)\'}/", function($m) {
  return include($m[1]);
}, $str);
```

Comment: Thanks! I already thought about `preg_replace_callback`. It works excellent. On changing PHP regular expression to `(.*?)`, it returns also multiple `include`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**`preg_replace_callback()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) :

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/\{include '(.*)\'}/", function ($matches) {
    // TODO, here : some test on $matches[1], to make sure that including it is safe
    return include $matches[1];
}, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/\{include '(.*)\'}/", function($matches){finclude($matches[1]);}, $str);
```